# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime - Image to byte[] and Vice Versa

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, arrays, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

For my application, I am trying to convert an `WriteableBitmap` to `byte[]` to store in the database, and then from `byte[]` to `BitmapImage` to display back to the user.

My current methods that so far, produce no results:

```
public byte[] ConvertBitmapToByteArray(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
{
    using (Stream stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

To convert from byte array to `BitmapImage`, I use:

```
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{

    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        writer.WriteBytes((byte[])buffer);
        writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
    }


    var image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(ms);
    imageByteTest.Source = image;
}
```

There is good documentation for Silverlight applications I have found, but very little in the way for Windows Store Universal Runtime Applications.  Where are these methods going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library which contains some extensions to WriteableBitmap, as well as some core features like your conversion of WriteableBitmap to byte array and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a converter for ByteArrayToBitmapImage:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var byteArray = value as byte[];
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
                {
                    bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                }
            });

        return bitmapImage;

    }
```

And byte[] -> WriteableBitmap

```
  public static WriteableBitmap PrepareWritableBitmap(Size size, byte[] pixels)
    {
        uint height = (uint)Math.Floor(size.Height);
        uint width = (uint)Math.Floor(size.Width);

        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
        Stream pixStream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(width * height * 4));
        //4 is a channel number for RGBA, for RGB is 3 channels
        return bmp;
    }
```